# Use Javascript to send multiple requests to server until server returns 200

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, server, restart

I have created a html page which the user views when they are waiting for another application to restart. I have created a javascript script which makes multiple requests to the application until the application returns 200. However, when i try to open my html page, the browser simply crashes. Can anyone see whats wrong with my code:

```
var responseStatus = 404;
var numberOfTries = 0;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
while(responseStatus != 200){
    console.log("Checking if restart has completed. Attempt number: " + numberOfTries);
    request.open('GET', 'applicationurl', true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (request.readyState === 4){
            console.log("Request Status: " + request.status);
            responseStatus = request.status;
            console.log("Response Status: " + request.status);
            if (request.status != 200) {  
                numberOfTries++;
                console.log("Restart has not yet completed! NumberOfTries: " + numberOfTries);
            }  
        }
    };
    request.send();
}
console.log("Server has successfully restarted");
```

Comment: put come delay in you code using setTimeout method,
you are continuously hitting server with while thats why your browser simply crashe.

Comment: The console doesn't log anything after the first log. The browser freezes and i need to force quit and reopen the browser to access html pages again.

Comment: @rurounisergii again, this is because you're doing this in a loop. You will actually be sending hundreds, if not thousands of requests until one succeeds. Even then, even if you do get a 200 back, you will have likely send hundreds beforehand, since you are not waiting for them to return and they are all sent asynchronously.

Comment: Good way to DDoS yourself. And using a while loop with an Asynchronous call is not going to work.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this (in my opinion) is to actually combine @serge1peshcoff's two options.  Write the call as a function that calls itself when the response fails, *and* set a timeout when doing so.  For most purposes, you don't want to send another request immediately after the previous one, you want to wait at least a second or five to prevent spamming the server (you've also given no indication of how many clients you expect.  What's bad for your browser is potentially horrible for the server, which may be handling requests even before your web app is fully up and returning 200).

Also, setTimeout is a better approach than setInterval, as you explicitly reset it on each round trip.

Borrowing from @serge:

```
function tryRequest(numTries) {
  var responseStatus = 404;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  numTries = numTries || 0;

  console.log("Checking if restart has completed. Attempt number: " + numAttempts);
  request.open('GET', 'applicationurl', true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      numTries++

      if (request.readyState === 4){
          console.log("Request Status: " + request.status);
          responseStatus = request.status;
          console.log("Response Status: " + request.status);
          if (request.status != 200) {  
              console.log("Restart has not yet completed! NumberOfTries: " + this.attempts);
              setTimeout(tryRequest.bind(null, numTries), 5000); // five seconds
          }  
      }
  };
  request.send();

  console.log("Server has successfully restarted");
}
tryRequest();
```

Comment: Why won't you pass `numAttempts` as an argument to `tryRequest`? It seems to me that doing `this.attempts = this.attempts || 0; this.attempts++;` won't work, because when you are calling `setTimeout`, you pass `tryAttempts` to it without arguments and `this.attempts` will be recreated every time

Comment: How would you make the function exit after a certain amount of tries?

Comment: Updated my code to account for the `this` scope problem that I introduced by passing in the param instead.  @rurounisergii if you want to exit after a certain number of tries, just set up the test and return before calling setTimeout again.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sends a multiple requests, however it doesn't wait for them to respond.

Here is how it works:

- an `XMLHttpRequest` is created
- a callback and a data is assigned to it
- this object is sent to server
- then the `while` loop ends and runs again, not waiting for the callback to be run

As a result, a lot of `XMLHttpRequest` objects are created and a lot of requests are run simultaneously, which is not what you want.

You can do this 2 ways:

- wrapping it into a function and call it when it fails (preferrable);
- setting some interval to wait for response

1st approach:

```
function tryRequest(numAttempts) {
  var responseStatus = 404;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

  console.log("Checking if restart has completed. Attempt number: " + numAttempts);
  request.open('GET', 'applicationurl', true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (request.readyState === 4){
          console.log("Request Status: " + request.status);
          responseStatus = request.status;
          console.log("Response Status: " + request.status);
          if (request.status != 200) {  
              console.log("Restart has not yet completed! NumberOfTries: " + numAttempts);
              tryRequest(numAttempts + 1)
          }  
      }
  };
  request.send();

  console.log("Server has successfully restarted");
}
tryRequest(0);
```

2nd approach:

```
var responseStatus = 404;
var numberOfTries = 0;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var interval = setInterval(tryRequest, 1000)

function tryRequest() {
  console.log("Checking if restart has completed. Attempt number: " + numberOfTries);
  request.open('GET', 'applicationurl', true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (request.readyState === 4){
          console.log("Request Status: " + request.status);
          responseStatus = request.status;
          console.log("Response Status: " + request.status);
          if (request.status != 200) {
              numberOfTries++;
              console.log("Restart has not yet completed! NumberOfTries: " + numberOfTries);
          } else {
              clearInterval(interval);
              console.log("Server has successfully restarted");
          }
      }
  };
  request.send();
  }

}
```

(disclaimer: I didn't test both of then)

Comment: The interval method should abort the call if it is still open.

Comment: @epascarello yeah, you're right, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Code like

```
var responseStatus = 404;
var numberOfTries = 0;
function check(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        console.log("Checking if restart has completed. Attempt number: " + numberOfTries);
        request.open('GET', 'applicationurl', true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (request.readyState === 4){
               console.log("Request Status: " + request.status);
               responseStatus = request.status;
               console.log("Response Status: " + request.status);
               if (request.status != 200) {  
                  numberOfTries++;
                  console.log("Restart has not yet completed! NumberOfTries: " + numberOfTries);
                   var tmp = setTimeout(function(){ check() },5000 ); // check after 5 second
               }  elseif (request.status == 200) {  
                    console.log("Server has successfully restarted");
               }
            }
        };
        request.send();

  }
```

// Call first time

```
check();
```